# How to open S Voice using Android Programming

Tags: android, android-intent, voice-recognition

I am using Android 5.0 in Galaxy S4. When I double press in the home button, the S Voice is open. I want to make the code open it. I used the below code but the code only opens google voice. How can I open S Voice without any configuration? Thank you so much

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Oops! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

This is S-Voice

[image]

Update: I installed the software Dexplorer, and found the Svoice. However, I cannot access to see the AndroidManifest.xml

[image]

Comment: i am not sure if this can help you.. but give it a shot.. use this app called dexplorer https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dexplorer&hl=en. it shows you a list of all intents an app provides that are installed on your device.

Comment: Sorry. The S voice is build in app (default app ) in galaxy. I installed your suggested app but it does not show s voice

Comment: under preference you have an option to show system apps also

Comment: Do you mean you want to broadcast an Intent that will start S-Voice in listening mode?

Comment: Thank you. But I cannot see the AndroidManifest.xml to know how to call the intent. @ brandall: I want to turn on the S Voice app from Android Intent

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still not sure what you want to achieve... Do you want to start S-Voice with it listening directly from your code?

Comment: Yes. Instead of double click on home button to call the S-Voice app. I want to call it by programming. Is it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of S-Voice I have installed will respond to any of the following intent actions:

```
            final String SVOICE_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.vlingo.midas";
            final String SVOICE_LISTEN_ACTION = "com.sec.action.SVOICE";

            final Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setPackage(SVOICE_PACKAGE_NAME);

            intent.setAction(SVOICE_LISTEN_ACTION);

            // intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND);

            // intent.setAction(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_VOICE_SEARCH_HANDS_FREE);
            // intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SECURE, false);

            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (final ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Good job. I got it

Comment: Do you know How can I return/exit the S voice by code. I call other Intent as Home. It does not allow

Comment: @user8430 You mean close S-Voice and go to the launcher or back to your app?

Comment: I just want to go Home screen. For example, as above code to go S Voice. I have another code to go Home as follows. When I am in S Voice,  I cannot  use the code to go Home. My code to go Home is             `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startActivity(intent);`

Comment: @user8430 Your application will be in the background and 'paused/destroyed' when S-Voice is launched. Are you sure your Intent code is executing correctly? The alternative is to run a service and launch the intent from there.

Comment: I sure with above code. When I am not in S voice, I can call Home screen and then Svoice. However, If I choose Svoice first, I cannot return the Home screen with above code

Comment: @user8430 You need to investigate running a service or setting up a broadcast receiver to fire the intent from that Context. There's no guarantee that your app won't be immediately destroyed, when another starts - so you have to code assuming that will 'always' be the case.

Comment: Thanks. I got the results. However, it has a new issue. Could you look at the issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340591/how-to-determine-get-correct-s-voice-packet-in-android